# Dos colores en la misma palabra en html

Tags: html

necesito poner dos colores en la misma palabra en html, la palabra esta dentro de una etiqueta h1, todo lo que intento hace que media palabra vaya a una segunda línea
por ejemplo

```
<h1>promociones</h1>
```

Comment: Deberías añadir a qué te refieres con dos colores en una palabra. Ya hay alguna pregunta para tener la mitad de un color y la otra mitad del otro (tanto en vertical como en horizontal). También deberías añadir un ejemplo de intento que hiciste y como no funcionó. Lee [ask] y [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si te queda corto las clases o id para insertar más colores en una palabra:

```html
<h1><span style="color:green">MAR</span><span style="color:yellow">IHU</span><span style="color:red">ANA<span></h1>
```

Simplemente cada parte de tu palabra o frase que quieras cambiar el color en ciérralo con un span y le pones el color que quieras pero si solo son pocos los colores que quieras cambiar en una palabra usa una clase o un id como el ejemplo de arriba para que mantengas estética en el codigo.

Comment: muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 5):

Puedes dividirla mediante elementos span, asignando diferentes colores, por ejemplo:

```css
h1 { color: blue }
span { color: red }
```

```html
<h1><span>promo</span>ciones</h1>
```

Comment: genial, era lo que quería, muchas gracias!!!